Ubuntu fsck seems to do nothing but chkdsk fixes it
I have a hard drive that frequently gets orphaned index files making it impossible to delete directories on it.
I'm using Ubuntu 22 so I try running fsck (sudo fsck /dev/sdb2) and all it does is return successful status code and print "fsck from util-liinux 2.37.2" to the terminal. There's no delay as if no process actually went through to check files and such. But the problem persists.
So then, I switch over to Windows 11 (dual booted, this hard drive in question is a separate HDD, not the boot drive) and run the chkdsk command to do the same thing (chkdsk E: /f) and that command actually runs through a bunch of checks and even fixes the issue by deleting all the orphaned indexes. I switch back to Ubuntu and voila, I can remove the directory I wanted to.
Why isn't fsck doing anything here?

what filesystem is on the disk? you should stick to using native tools for maintaining a given filesystem type, so use windows for NTFS, and Linux for extX/btrfs/etc.

Totally with @FrankThomas .. I like having the foreign drivers one each side, but I don't trust them unless I must.

Ah, I ran df -T and it is ntfs3. I didn't realize file systems are native to particular OS's. So does that mean I should just switch over to Windows when I need to fix the drive then?

If you want to put this as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted

Linux has had a long and troubled history when it comes to proprietary Microsoft technologies like SMB, ACPI, and in this case, the NTFS file system.
In order to support a filesystem, you must install a driver that knows how to use it. In Linux there are two common drivers, the older NTFS-3g, and the newer NTFS3. Most common distributions ship one or the other or both for out-of-box use (they have some differing usecases, so might as well have both).
NTFS-3g has supported both read and write since 2007, but most distros limited it to read-only operations for a good number of years, and many people refused to use it due to concerns about maturity and it was strongly advised that a user not enable write operations on any disk they cared about. Even today, when RW operations for NTFS are generally enabled by default, NTFS-3G and its supporting utilities aren't at 100% parity with the Microsoft implementation. In fact I would not be surprised to find that the issues you are having with orphaned indexes was caused by Linux use of the filesystem.
NTFS3 does not yet have freely available disk maintenance utilities per their FAQ.
NTFS-3G ships a package called ntfsfix that can be invoked by fsck (fsck.ntfs). ntfsfix however is very clear in it's documentation:

ntfsfix is a utility that fixes some common NTFS problems. ntfsfix is NOT a Linux version of chkdsk. It only repairs some fundamental NTFS inconsistencies, resets the NTFS journal file and schedules an NTFS consistency check for the first boot into Windows.
You may run ntfsfix on an NTFS volume if you think it was damaged by Windows or some other way and it cannot be mounted.

So fsck can only perform a subset of the repair operations that chkdsk uses when performing a filesystem repair, and specific to your case, checking for and repairing orphaned Indexes is one of those gaps.


In fact I would not be surprised to find that the issues you are having with orphaned indexes was caused by Linux use of the filesystem.




Yeah I use this drive for development so I'm constantly compiling, editing, and running software off of it. And before I upgraded RAM, my comp would sometimes crash due to maxed out RAM in the middle of transpilation (node apps take a horrendous amount of time to transpile) and such. That's when I would usually start seeing the orphaned indexes when I turn my computer back on.
